# “Associated statement not prepared” caused by pypyodc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

What - Error Message (‘HY007’, [HY007][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Associated statement Is not prepared.

I downloaded ODBC to better diagnose this error based off other posts, however it is still throwing the same error

What is the actually error here and what is the way around it?

```
Import requests
Import pandas as pd 
Import pypyodbc
Import matplotlib.pypot as ply

Conn1 = pypyodbc.connect(“Driver={SQL Server};” “Server = DESKTOP-KOOxxx;” “Database = Horsesxx;” “Trusted_Connection=yes;”, autocommit=True)

Mycursor = Conn1.cursor()

Mycursor.execute(‘Drop table #temptable SELECT * into #temptable FROM (SELECT HorseName, DayCalender FROM horses WHERE Place = 1) AS T1 Inner Join (SELECT runnerName, day, WIN_ODDS_BSP FROM betfairdata) AS T3 ON T1.HorseName = T3.runnerName AND T1.DayCalender = T3.day SELECT WIN_ODDS_BSP FROM #temptable)

Conn1.commit()
```

This statement works within SQL yet not within VS

Statement also works if I drop the temp table components

Comment: Maybe a typo, but I don't see a closing single quote on the statement.

Comment: Yes typo sorry. With included it is the same result

Comment: `Drop table #temptable` will error if #temptable doesn't already exist on the connection. How about `drop table if exists #temptable;`?